# How can we check docusign email status check and Notification?

Tags: docusignapi

Once any document is sent for signature, we can see that document status like in process, completed. Also email notification is coming to document sender mail. Are these features exposed by docusign rest API?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please be sure to upvote all usefule answers, including those to others' questions. And please check the best answer to your own questions.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, absolutely. The status updates are delivered to your program via a "webhook" -- you register a url with DocuSign and then DocuSign calls your app when a change occurs.

You can create a webhook subscription at the account level or for individual envelopes.

See the [docs](https://docs.docusign.com/esign/guide/usage/status_and_events.html). Recipes are also available at the DocuSign Developer Center.

**Added**

You can also determine the current status of your signing requests (your envelopes) by polling the DocuSign platform. However, this is actively discouraged, and in any case, you can't poll more than once per 15 minutes for a given envelope. The [docs](https://docs.docusign.com/esign/guide/usage/status_and_events.html) discuss this as well.

Comment: Thanks for your reply .Can you please confirm without creating Webhook is it possible to get status and notification from docusign .I have found out one code in Recipes .Is that code works for this feature

Comment: @Souravsanyal, I added to my reply

Comment: @Lary-Then which one is the best option to get envelope status

Comment: The best is to use the webhook feature since it gives you much faster status updates. The per-envelope "eventNotification" webhook feature is included with all account types.

Comment: I am using c# code for my own application .Do you have any code in c# for accessing webhook

Comment: Unfortunately we don't have the Webhook recipe translated into C# yet. It is on the roadmap. You just write a small web server app that receives the incoming XML POSTS from DocuSIgn. I'd look a simple framework. Remember that you won't need a "view" layer, just a controller to handle the incoming requests and a model (db) to store the new info.

Comment: Can you please let me know from where we can get that incoming XML posts from docusign

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand your comment. The DocuSign platform calls your website.

Comment: I can understand your point Larry. Can you please give me the  link where i can get that code to call my website from docusign platform .I am little bit confused about this calling .